# form select element selected unique

Tags: html

I want to let my user to order a select from my database, and I created 3 select elements on my form to get that done.

```
<select name="options1select">
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority1select">
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>

<select name="options2select">
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority2select">
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>

<select name="options3select">
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority3select">
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>
```

How is the best way to let the user only select name, games or points once?

What I want is: if the user chooses name on the first select, he will not be able to select name on the second and third.

Comment: you mean after pick it is locked?

Comment: yes, the choice can't be repeated.

Comment: if you don't have blank as the first option then all 3 would be name on page load.

Comment: @ledesma with js? jQuery? with only HTML I think that's hard

Answer (score 0):

If you want allow user to choose only one item, you should use radio instead of select.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear, but what I want is: if the user chooses name on the first select, he will not be able to select name on the second and third.

Comment: Oh. You can't achieve something like this with HTML only. You'll need to write a piece of JavaScript, which should check user's choice on first checkbox and disable it on the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you can do it with jquery : (add id="smth" to use it)

```
<script>
var selection = function () {
if ($("#putAnId").is(":checked")) {
    $(a"#theOtherId").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else {
    //other insctructions
}
};

$(selection);
$("#putAnId").change(selection);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q518o1pc/

If you use jQuery and you add a blank option to your 3 drop downs all you have to do is:

```
$("#options1select").on("change", function() {
     if ( $(this).val() == $("#options2select").val() ||
        $(this).val() == $("#options3select").val() ) {
        $(this).val("");
      } 
});

$("#options2select").on("change", function() {
     if ( $(this).val() == $("#options1select").val() ||
                            $(this).val() == $("#options3select").val() ) {
                    $(this).val("");
      } 
});

$("#options3select").on("change", function() {
     if ( $(this).val() == $("#options1select").val() ||
        $(this).val() == $("#options2select").val() ) {
            $(this).val("");
      } 
});
```

The HTML would be:

```
<select name="options1select" id="options1select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority1select">
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>

<select name="options2select" id="options2select">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority2select">
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>

<select name="options3select" id="options3select">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority3select">
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple with jQuery.

use `$('select[name^=options]')` you can get all select with name **started** with `options`

use `$('select[name^=options] > option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']')` get all the same option under select and disable all of them (since you picked you disable all other same option)

Also, disable yourself so you can't change it anymore.

```js
$('select[name^=options]').on('change', function() {
  $('select[name^=options] > option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
})

$('select[name^=piority]').on('change', function() {
  $('select[name^=piority] > option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options1select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority1select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>

<select name="options2select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority2select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>

<select name="options3select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="games">games</option>
  <option value="points">points</option>
</select>
<select name="piority3select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="asc">asc</option>
  <option value="desc">desc</option>
</select>
```